# text of span doesn't update in html

Tags: jquery, html

I have below html code

```
<span id="remain_1">423</span>
```

I use this code for update it's text

```
$("#remain_1").text("gfdgfd");
```

In jquery it's value is updating, `$("#remain_1").text()` it returns me gfdgfd
, but in html code, it doesn't update. What's problem?

this is full of on item that I want to be edited.

```
<div class="col s6 m3 l2">

                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-image">
                        <a href="/product/3/محصول-شماره-یک">
                            <img src="/files/test.jpg" alt="محصول شماره یک">
                        </a>
                        <span id="remain_1">423</span>
                        <a class="btn-floating halfway-fab waves-effect waves-light red" onclick="addToCart(3)"><i class="material-icons">add_shopping_cart</i></a>
                    </div><br>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <a href="/product/3/محصول-شماره-یک">
                            <small class="small">محصول شماره یک</small>
                        </a>    
                        <br>
                        <span class="green-text">423 تومان</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

                        </div>
```

and jquery code

```
function addToCart(product_id){
        $("#remain_1").text("gfdgfd");

        localStorage.setItem("products", localStorage.getItem("products") + "," + product_id);
        $("#cart_items_count").text(parseInt($("#cart_items_count").text()) + 1);

        $("#remain_" + product_id).trigger("change");

        Materialize.toast($("#remain_" + product_id).text(), 2000);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean? I've just copied your code to jsfiddle and it works fine

Comment: Here is a working codepen : https://codepen.io/andreds/pen/RQbqvY Are you sure you're not having multiple elements with ID "remain_1" ?

Comment: Could I see the whole HTML and JS code please?

Comment: @AndréDS it would still work even with multiple duplicated IDs

Comment: @AndréDS yes, ids are unique

Comment: I have updated question

Comment: I don't see a problem... have you tried removing all the other lines of code in your `addToCart` function or put `return true` after `$("#remain_1").text("gfdgfd");`? I have a theory that the other lines of code are creating the problem.

Comment: @TomMcPadden 
 
I restarted firefox and problem gone away. Sorry, it seems bug of firefox

Comment: lol stupid firefox. Good luck with your project.